# Multiline Text Box Not showing the contents while loading the page using back button in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

Now I am working in creating Installers using NSIS. In one of my custom page, I have created the Multiline Text Box and load the contents from reading the text file. It was working fine while the page loading... But after navigating to the next page, I have just clicked the back button.. While the page loading it displays only the Mulitline text box and not the contents. And also again click back buton from the current page and after clicked next button, the page loads with the contents. This not works only for clicking back button.. I dont know why this is happening.. Could anyone help me to figure out the problem?

Following is my custom page function

```
Function PrePage
    ; Set dialog text:
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "$(RELEASENOTEDIA_TITLE)" "RELEASENOTEDIA_SUBTITLE"

    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $dialog

    FileOpen $4 "$path\PreRequisite.txt" r
    StrCpy $3 ""
    loop:
    FileRead $4 $1
    StrCpy $3 "$3$1" ; append the line and copy it to another variable
    IfErrors +1 loop   
    FileClose $4

    nsDialogs::CreateControl EDIT \
        "${__NSD_Text_STYLE}|${WS_VSCROLL}|${ES_READONLY}|${WS_HSCROLL}|${ES_MULTILINE}|${ES_WANTRETURN}" \
        "${__NSD_Text_EXSTYLE}" \
        0 10% 100% 90% \
        "$3"
        Pop $hwnd

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me, could something be changing $path on another page?

Add `MessageBox mb_ok handle=$4,path=$path` after FileOpen, $4 should **not** be "" or 0...

Comment: I have checked today without any code changes.. It is working fine for me.. But I don't know in which scenario it fails? Thank you for your Suggestion..